# IE stop working while JavaScript is running some operations

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, events

I have a list of radio-buttons and check-boxes and I want to monitor their events to get their values

once they are clicked I want to run some logic on the values

now what I see is that it slow down rendering time for the actual change in IE8/IE9

what happens now is that I see the view wait for the result and it looks weird
all other browsers breeze through it

but IE is not that much

here is a sample code

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" id="t" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
        if (elem.addEventListener){
            elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
        }else if (elem.attachEvent){
            elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler);
        }
    }

        var el = document.getElementById("t");

    addEventHandler( document.getElementById("t") , 'click' , function(){
        for(var i=0;i<30000000;i++);// the for loop is only to show the blocking behavior that OP is experiencing
        alert("handled")
    } );
</script>
</html>
```

how can I prevent the ie view from stopping and waiting for JavaScript till finish the it operations?

Comment: it may be slow due to the pointless 30 million loop iterations you have.

Comment: Yes this: `for(var i=0;i<30000000;i++);` is a mistake.

Comment: and why it is working very fine in other browsers ?

Comment: @jbabey He's built a **Click-erciser**!

Comment: the 30 million loop iterations is the estimated time that my javascript operations last

Comment: most likely the other browsers' javascript engines are smart enough to see that your loops are pointless and ignores them. IE probably does not, hence the difference.

Comment: @AymanJitan you're doing it wrong.  There's almost no circumstance in which that's a good approach to making software work.

Comment: @AymanJitan–so you are asking the browser to wait while it executes 3e7 loops, then complain when it does that. I think your expectations are unrealistic.

Comment: @RobG you got me wrong , I was asking why IE keeps waiting till JavaScript finishes, that was my question

Comment: @Pointy: I really think the loop is just being used to show the blocking behavior that OP is experiencing.

Comment: @AymanJitan In **all** browsers, JavaScript execution is synchronous.  The browser waits because that's what it's supposed to do. Other, newer browsers simply optimize JavaScript better than IE, so they take less time - but they still wait.

Comment: As everyone else has already stated, its waiting because it's supposed to. Javascript is single threaded. So it literally CAN'T move on until the current code is done, and returns up the call stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"how can I prevent the ie view from stopping and waiting for JavaScript till finish the it operations?"*

You can't prevent IE from waiting for JavaScript. By waiting, it's behaving correctly.

Best you can do is improve your code so that it doesn't take so long to execute, or break it up into smaller chunks that are executed asynchronously.

Comment: and why it works very fine on other browsers like firefox and google chroome ?

Comment: @AymanJitan: They're faster. Can't tell much more without seeing your code. Different browsers have different optimizations.

Comment: Simply put @user1689607 has it right. IE is an ancient browser that I doubt will ever catch up speed wise with Firefox, Chrome et al. no matter how much effort MS put into it (which is not much tbh).